# Why doesn't Swift binary built by CMake Ninja generator, generate logs to terminal using Logger framework?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, cmake, ninja

This behaviour is only observed with Ninja generator and not seen with Xcode generator. Just replace Ninja with Xcode in the commands(mentioned below). Is there any post build steps to be run for a Ninja build, which is causing this?

UPDATE: The binary built from Xcode, when ran in shell, doesn't print the log too. So, Xcode does it set some environment variable or anything else to make it behave differently?

I am trying below code in Swift file

```
import Foundation
import os.log

extension Logger {
    /// Using your bundle identifier is a great way to ensure a unique identifier.
    private static var subsystem = "com.sadfdfd.com2" 
    // private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!

    /// Logs the view cycles like a view that appeared.
    static let viewCycle = Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: "viewcycle")

    /// All logs related to tracking and analytics.
    static let statistics = Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: "statistics")
}

var now = NSDate()
print("This NSDate object lives at ", Unmanaged.passUnretained(now).toOpaque())

// Logger is only logging when using Xcode app and not in shell - cmake --build Debug and running from there.
Logger.statistics.debug("The current date is \(now.description)")
```

CMakeLists.txt file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(swifthello LANGUAGES Swift)
add_executable(helloworld main.swift)
```

command to build a Ninja generator

```
  cmake -G "Ninja" -H. -BDebug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=YES
cmake --build Debug
```

Binary is generated in Debug directory.

Open the Xcode project from Debug directory and build, run for the helloworld project.

output generated in Xcode console

This NSDate object lives at  0x27a14adf6b43de75

2023-08-21 11:39:07.530163+0530 helloworld[11111:332575] [statistics] The current date is 2023-08-21 06:09:07 +0000

output generated by Ninja generator

This NSDate object lives at  0x27a14adf6b43de75

Expect the same output as generated by Xcode compiled binary.